# Any MySQL Node Package: `USE index` with SELECT Statement

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, node-modules, node-mysql

I am using a node module `sql` and finding support of running SQL with given Index:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 **USE INDEX (col_index)**
WHERE col1=1 AND col2=2 AND col3=3;
```

But I am not able to find this support in this Module.

Please help here how can I run the mentioned SQL with my SQL ORM. Or any Alternative way.

Comment: Does this fail? Do you get errors? Show us the errors if you get them and the code as well

Comment: @RiggsFolly This SQL is fine but The npm package `sql` that I am using, has no support of running SELECT statement with use index. Here I am stuck.

Comment: So how do you know that?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have explored SQL package directory. Can you help with any alternative

Comment: I admit I am not nodejs proficient, but I would expect node to just pass the DML to the DBMS for execution, So I would hope to be able to code any valid DML and for it to be executed and just a result returned to me

Comment: @RiggsFolly agree with your point. Running raw SQL queries through ORM is the last hope. I was looking for ORM methods.